# Software to import stl file to walk around it in 3D?

Tags: cad, file-format

I was wondering if there's any sort of software where you can import a `.stl` file and sort of walk around in it. I have a small house model exported as a `.stl` file and I kind of want to do just that. Anyway I don't really care if you can go through walls, I just want to be in it. I use [Tinkercad](https://tinkercad.com) to create these designs, but it's not easy to look around the inside. So if there's some software for developers making games or something that will do this, could you please let me know? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Meshmixer](https://www.meshmixer.com/) (Windows, MacOS) is a free program that allows STL files to be imported for examination and editing. You can "travel" into the model, but you're effectively passing through the surfaces you encounter. Depending on the scale of the model, you may have zero problems.

I've found that sometimes I get too close and lose reference, but you may not have that problem with a larger scale item like a house model.

For creating a video, you'd have to use a screen-capture utility.

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is another free multi-platform program that is used for animation as well as 3D modeling. It has far more power and is much more capable of performing the tasks you require. It has a substantial learning curve, but an equally substantial trove of tutorials on the internet.

You can control the "camera" location, lighting, coloration and so much more. You would not animate the house model, but you'd use camera controls to provide walkthroughs as desired. No additional software would be required to create videos as the program was designed for such purposes.